# how to connect to openvpn from shell

Tags: 12.04, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect from an ubuntu shell to a client VPN (OpenVPN). On mac I was able to do it using tunnelblick but now I need to do it from an ubuntu server.

I have tried:

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/vpn_config/openvpn-files$ ls
AVORA-duo.conf  ca.crt  luca.puggini.crt  luca.puggini.key
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/vpn_config/openvpn-files$ openvpn AVORA-duo.conf
Mon Jul  2 03:51:57 2018 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  4 2014
Enter Auth Username:luca.puggini
Enter Auth Password:
Mon Jul  2 03:52:28 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Mon Jul  2 03:52:28 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[133120->131072] S=[133120->131072]
Mon Jul  2 03:52:28 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jul  2 03:52:28 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]54.77.214.131:1194
Mon Jul  2 03:53:28 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Jul  2 03:53:28 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Jul  2 03:53:28 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Jul  2 03:53:28 2018 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Mon Jul  2 03:53:30 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Mon Jul  2 03:53:30 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[133120->131072] S=[133120->131072]
Mon Jul  2 03:53:30 2018 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jul  2 03:53:30 2018 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]54.77.214.131:1194
```

But I do not think it is working as I am not able to access to the local services.   (I am running on the `codeanywhere` shell)

what is the right way to use the `openvpn` function? Should I pass it also the other files (`.crt`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the **config** paramenter?

In your case it would be:

```
openvpn --config AVORA-duo.conf
```

.. and if all the files are stored in the folder `/etc/openvpn/`, then it would be automaticly loaded during startup (assuming openvpn is part of the startup of course).